# Why did Paizo say they dropped the evil subtype from Animate Dead?

Tags: campaign-settings, designer-reasons, starfinder

I was reading the new Starfinder Core Rulebook and as going through the spells section, I stumbled upon Animate Dead lacking the evil subtype (which was there in Pathfinder). Further reading the spells I saw that subtypes still exist, but I found no spell with the evil or good subtypes. Does this mean creating undead is now suddenly OK? Is there a setting reason for this?

There is a minor note in the part about bone sages (the necromancer lords of Eox): "[a bone sage] contrary to  popular  rumor,  is  not  so  much  evil  as  coldly  amoral  and  utilitarian." (Starfinder Core Rules page 451) This provides a bit of support that raising undead is not evil anymore. But doesn't answere the question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64970/discussion-on-question-by-molagmal-why-did-paizo-say-they-dropped-the-evil-subty).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [designer-reasons questions are no longer allowed on RPG.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This forum](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2uiha&page=1?NonEvil-Necromancy) hosts a slew of dev quotes, including (emphasis added):

> 1) something in the universe **changed on a metaphysical level**, in which case we would like an explanation on that since that's not mechanics like BAB and classes, that's a fundamental way in which the universe functions that has completely changed.
>
> 2) something more and more brought, and kinda danced around, is that **Starfinder is not an alternate future** to Pathfinder, but a future to an alternate Pathfindee [sic] where **things have always been this way**, which raises so many more questions and implications...

— paraphrased from Sutter and Moreland

> At first, I really struggled with meshing the two games' continuities in my own head, and I'm the in-house continuity wonk. Eventually, I was able to get over small (and some larger) differences between the two by **recognizing that they're different games. There's Pathfinder continuity and Starfinder continuity**, and while some elements are the same in both, they're a Venn diagram, not a continuum.

— Mark Moreland

So it would seem **the creative developers don't have an exact reasoning for the changes**. It is clear that they don't intend for Undead and their creation to be inherently Evil anymore, but have indicated that is is more often than not still Evil. Comments about the [Incident at Absolom Station AP](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9tmf?Starfinder-Adventure-Path-Incident-at-Absalom-Station) corroborate this.

Comment: The creative director of Starfinder is on record saying that SF undead aren't Evil because he wanted to play more non-evil undead, unlike James Jacobs (PF's creative director).

http://paizo.com/products/btpy9tmf/discuss&page=7?Starfinder-Adventure-Path-Incident-at-Absalom-Station#319